# Rewrite images directory IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

We are migrating a legacy application to ASP.NET MVC, but in the old application the images folder was in the root of the app, so to reference an images the path would be /images/imagename.png, but we want to move the images in to /Content/images in the new application but we dont want to change the paths in all the css and the html.

Is there a way to do a rewrite to the images folder so that every URL that goes to /images goes to /Content/images instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use URL Rewrite.  You need to install it via WebPI, then add the following to your web.config in system.webServer:

```
 <rewrite>
    <rule name="Old Images" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^images/(.+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="content/images/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
 </rewrite>
```